# CodeIgniter & JQuery - Commenting is not working after first posting

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

Thank for reading my question.

I had been trying to figure out what is the problem on the code.
My commenting is not working after the first post.

When I clicked on "Post New Message", then it will echo all the database information.

Sorry, I'm still not allow to upload any image.

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $('#postComment').click(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: "<?= base_url() ?>index.php/comment/insertComments",
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                data: $('#comment').serialize(),
                async: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#ajax-loading').html('<img src="<?= base_url() ?>/assets/img/loading.gif" width="25px" height="25px" />');
                },
                success: function(data) {

                    $('#commentTextArea').val('');
                            var commentValue = $('#fieldValue').val();

                    if (data) {

                        $('#ajax-loading').html('<img src="<?= base_url() ?>/assets/img/loading.gif" width="25px" height="25px" />').hide();

                        var data = JSON.parse(data);

                            $('#commentHistory'+commentValue).hide().append(
                                    '<div style="background-color: lightblue; border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;  margin-bottom: 5px; width: 100%;">' +
                                    '<a class="pull-left" href="#">' +
                                    '<img style="margin-top: 9px; margin-left: 5px; border-radius: 5px; padding-left: 5px;" class="media-object" id="sub-photo" src="../../images/' + data[0].Image + '" alt="'+ data[0].Image +'">' +
                                    '</a>' +
                                    '<div class="media-body">' +
                                    '<h6 style="color: gray; border-bottom: gray double thin; padding-bottom: 5px">' +
                                    '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>' +
                                    //TimeStamp
                                    '</h6>' +
                                    '<p class="media-heading" style="margin-top: -10px; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bolder; font-family: arial">' + data[0].FirstName + data[0].LastName + '</p>' +
                                    '<p style="width: 400px; word-wrap:break-word;">' +
                                    data[0].Description +
                                    '</p>' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                    '</div>').fadeIn(2000);

                    } else {
                        $('#searchInner').html('no results found').show();
                    }

                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Controller

```
function insertComments() {

    $this -> load -> helper(array('form'));
    $this -> load -> helper('date');
    $this -> load -> library('form_validation');

    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('comment_message', 'Description', 'trim|required|min_length[1]');

    if ($this -> form_validation -> run() == FALSE) {

        $this -> load -> view('include/header');
        $this -> load -> view('register_failure');
        $this -> load -> view('include/footer');

    } else {

        $description = $_POST['comment_message'];

        //$description = htmlentities($this -> input -> post('comment_message', TRUE));
        $postID = $_POST['commentpost']['PostID']; //('commentpost');

        $session_data = $this -> session -> userdata('logged_in');
        $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];

        $studentID = $data['username'];

        $timestamp = time();

        $result = $this -> CommentModel -> insertComments($postID, $studentID, $description, $timestamp);

        $resultComment = $this -> CommentModel -> getComments();

        $this->output->set_header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        echo json_encode($resultComment);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is exactly happening? Is it not inserting? The JSON encode is not working? In the browser console, any javascript errors popping up?

I just noted the "JSON.parse", do a console.log on the data received, because you put a JSON header in the PHP, so I think it's not needed to parse the JSON again, since jQuery will return a JSON object... maybe it's just this

Comment: @MauricioA.Cinelli
Well, actually I'm trying to insert a comment on it and display out immediately without refreshing the page.
If without JSON.Parse, I cannot get the information inside the Object. :(

Comment: Strange, normally if you place JSON headers in the PHP, jQuery will automatically parse the JSON for you...

Instead of using the "$this->output->set_header", just use the "header" function.
Test the AJAX endpoint with a chrome app like Postman.

What can be happeing is that some PHP is throwing an error, and because of the JSON header, it's just not appearing. Try to remove the JSON header and try to see if any error shows up

Comment: No worries. This happens to everybody. I'm curious about the error. But what are you exactly getting from the server as a response?

Comment: http://s1103.photobucket.com/user/xiKane/media/Problem.png.html

This is the problem that I'm facing. :(

Comment: Well, you are receiving an array of posts, you JSON.parse it, and then yopu append the comment. Should be right... Is it not appending? or is it appending always the same comment?

Comment: @MauricioA.Cinelli
It append the different comment on different post.
But when I am trying to submit a comment after the first post. Then it will stop at the Controller and echo all of the information about my comment information.

Actually I just want to display the comment immediate after user submit the comment and it will display on the bottom of the comment.

http://s1103.photobucket.com/user/xiKane/media/Problem-1.png.html

Do you want to try out my website? So you can understand more.

Comment: oh, is it stopping at the controller?
try to add a "return false" on the last line of the "click" callback

Comment: If I understood correctly by what you said, you are not interrupting the form, and it is sending the form as it would normally do, so you end up in the page with JSON.

By putting a return false, you cancel the sending of the form.
If this doesn't solve, then I don't have a clue of what's happening there...

Comment: @MauricioA.Cinelli
I think I show you the link. So you can try it out.
StudentID: admin
Password: developer

http://socialedu.no-ip.org/socialedu/index.php/main/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I tested a little bit in there. And yes, that's exactly what I thought it was doing, sometimes it breaks the JS code and your form sends normally, without AJAX.

So I have a couple of things:

1. You have a lot of JS errors in there, so it makes other JS code stop, and maybe it makes your form behave normally and not use AJAX at all
2. Add a `return false` as the last statement of the `click` callback, so it interrupts the form sending
3. Validate for empty comment, as it makes a `500 internal error` :)
4. Your date doesn't show when you just create the comment

I tested and I got the error you described, then changed your code to mine with the `return false`, and it did solve.

Also, if you want to be bullet proof, on the controller, at the `insertComment` function, make the return JSON if the request comes from AJAX, otherwise redirect... like so:

```
if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
    // respond JSON
} else {
    // redirect
}
```

I hope this helps you fix this.
Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you so much and sorry for the late respond.

I will try it now. Thanks!

Comment: Mauricio A. Cinelli,
So basically the reason I cannot display the post comment immediate at second post is because of AJAX never send request to InsertComments?

I add in the link you mentioned. The return false; should code at the last sentences after the CLICK function been trigger?